# Why is getline faster than scanf here?

Tags: c++, scanf, getline

The code reads a line from stdin (max 30 characters) and counts it occurrences using std::map

```
std::map<std::string, int> mymap;
```

getline:

```
std::string str;
while (std::getline(std::cin,str))
    mymap[str]++;
```

scanf:

```
char str[30];
while(scanf("%30[^\n]%*c", str) != EOF)
    mymap[str]++;
```

With big input getline is almost 2X faster.

Shouldn't scanf be faster than getline?

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of information, like why scanf should be faster than getline, and your measurements.

Comment: This is not *too* surprising - `scanf` is a lot more flexible and general purpose in nature than `getline`.

Comment: I would expect `getline` to pretty much always be faster than `scanf`, a function which does much more than "look for a newline"

Comment: in case you didn't notice, even your `scanf` implementation is *still* constructing a `std::string` (the arg to `operator []` is not a `char const*` or `char*` ; a `std::string` will be constructed, whereas with the first version the existing `std::string` will simply be used by-reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason `scanf` should be faster than `getline`. In fact, in this case, you would expect the reverse. The `getline` function knows it needs to get a line, and is optimized for that purpose. The `scanf` function has to make sense of your format string and figure out that you're trying to read a line in a context where you could be requesting all kinds of other behaviors. So we would expect `getline` to be faster.

Comment: I agree that `scanf` is unlikely to be faster than `getline`. But there's 101 reasons why the difference could be something else - such as using `std::string` vs `char str[30]` to index into a `std::map<string, int>`, causing a temporary `std::string` to be created and destroyed for every call to `mymap[str]++` - just one of a dozen things that COULD be the reason.